# Why won't Yum install the latest version of Perl?

Tags: centos, yum, perl, software-updates

Why won't Yum install the latest version of Perl? I see that Perl is at 5.32.0 https://www.perl.org/get.html. My Perl is 5.10.1.

```
# perl -v
This is perl, v5.10.1
```

When I try to update, it doesn't do anything.

```
# yum update perl
No Packages marked for Update
```

Here is the info for Perl

```
# yum info perl.x86_64
Installed Packages
Name        : perl
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 4
Version     : 5.10.1
Release     : 144.el6
Size        : 34 M
Repo        : installed
Summary     : Practical Extraction and Report Language
URL         : http://www.perl.org/
```

Here is my repository list:

```
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: d36uatko69830t.cloudfront.net
 * centos-sclo-rh: d36uatko69830t.cloudfront.net
 * centos-sclo-sclo: d36uatko69830t.cloudfront.net
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
 * extras: d36uatko69830t.cloudfront.net
 * rpmforge: mirror.teklinks.com
 * updates: d36uatko69830t.cloudfront.net
repo id                                                                                             repo name                                                                                                                          status
Webmin                                                                                              Webmin Distribution Neutral                                                                                                           167
base                                                                                                CentOS-6 - Base                                                                                                                     6,713
centos-sclo-rh                                                                                      CentOS-6 - SCLo rh                                                                                                                  3,814
centos-sclo-sclo                                                                                    CentOS-6 - SCLo sclo                                                                                                                  436
epel                                                                                                Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                                                                     12,592
extras                                                                                              CentOS-6 - Extras                                                                                                                      47
pgdg93                                                                                              PostgreSQL 9.3 6 - x86_64                                                                                                             429
rpmforge                                                                                            RHEL 6 - RPMforge.net - dag                                                                                                         4,718
updates                                                                                             CentOS-6 - Updates                                                                                                                  1,068
repolist: 29,984
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's simply the newest version RedHat/CentOS provides. Bear in mind that CentOS is an enterprise distribution that is designed not to break during the normal lifecycle, so feature updates are pretty rare and bugfixes are often backported from newer versions to older ones.
That being said, you have Software Collections enabled, there should be a somewhat newer perl in there. (5.14? 5.16? I can't check right now, but `yum search rh-perl` should tell you.) Note that that perl will not replace `/usr/bin/perl`, it will install the new version into `/opt/rh/...`.

Comment: There is `rh-perl524.x86_64`.